# Can't hide element with effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I am trying to hide div **with effect**.

My JS is:

```
function hideDiv()
{
    $("#hide").hide(); // this works 
}
function hideDivE()
{
    $("#hide").hide("puff", {}, 2000); // this doesn't work
}
```

And HTML is:

```
<div id="hide">
    Hide this div
</div>
<button onclick="hideDiv()">Hide</button>
<button onclick="hideDivE()">Hide + effect</button>
```

If `.hide()` works, how comes that `.hide("puff", {}, 2000)` doesn't work?

Comment: Plain jQuery does not come with a "puff" effect.  Have you loaded some code that implements a "puff" effect?  It looks to me like perhaps it's part of the separate add-on library jQueryUI.

Comment: Try with `$("#hide").hide(2000);`

Comment: This works for me http://jsfiddle.net/fpzd3n3m/ did you include right versions of libraries?

Comment: Thank you all. I had to include jquery-ui library.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was solved by using the library that was referenced, and a problem caused by forgetfulness or absent-mindedness. Yes, we've all experienced that, but it's still unlikely that this question will be of use to others in future.

Comment: My bad. Was exhausted last night.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson: if something doesn't work - check if you **imported proper libraries.**

Just included jquery-ui.js to get it to work.